# Flex box prevent overflow and keep the right item fixed width and left item shrink

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I don't have problem keeping the left item having a fixed width using the `flex-basis` property. But I have a scenario wherein I don't want the left element to be fixed and keep the right element's width fixed instead. I tried putting `flex-basis` for the right element however, the problem is the flex items overflow its container.

Is there a way to achieve this? For example I have the layout below:

[image]

```css
.flex-outer {
  display: flex;
}

.dashboard {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.col {
  margin-left: 25px;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  background: orange;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-outer">
  <div class="dashboard">
    <ul class="flex-container">
      <li class="flex-item">1</li>
      <li class="flex-item">2</li>
      <li class="flex-item">3</li>
      <li class="flex-item">4</li>
      <li class="flex-item">5</li>
      <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col">

  </div>
</div>
```

### Question

What I want to do is keep the right element (orange) `200px` in a fixed width and just shrink the left flex-item (red) based on the available space. However, the problem is the right element is overflowing the container when the viewport is too narrow see image below.

[image]

Comment: Do you want 2 list item in a same row?

Comment: Your image is not loading for me.

Comment: i still dont get it. What is difference between 2 your images? The red element still take all the remain space

Comment: Posted an answer. What should happen to the left items when there is no space left in the viewport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `flex-shrink` defaults to `1`, it means `.col` is allowed to shrink below the given `200px`.

Add `flex-shrink: 0` to the `.col` rule and it won't.

Stack snippet

```css
.flex-outer {
  display: flex;
}

.dashboard {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.col {
  margin-left: 25px;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;                       /*  added  */
  background: orange;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-outer">
  <div class="dashboard">
    <ul class="flex-container">
      <li class="flex-item">1</li>
      <li class="flex-item">2</li>
      <li class="flex-item">3</li>
      <li class="flex-item">4</li>
      <li class="flex-item">5</li>
      <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col">

  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you also want to completely avoid the `orange` box being pushed out of view, and as `min-width` defaults to `auto`, which means the `dashboard` and the `flex-container` won't get smaller than their content, you also need to set `min-width: 0` to both of them so they will.

Stack snippet

```css
.flex-outer {
  display: flex;
}

.dashboard {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 0;                         /*  added  */
}
.col {
  margin-left: 25px;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;                       /*  added  */
  background: orange;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  min-width: 0;                         /*  added  */
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-outer">
  <div class="dashboard">
    <ul class="flex-container">
      <li class="flex-item">1</li>
      <li class="flex-item">2</li>
      <li class="flex-item">3</li>
      <li class="flex-item">4</li>
      <li class="flex-item">5</li>
      <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col">

  </div>
</div>
```

---

A second option to handle the left items is of course to set `flex-wrap: wrap` to the `flex-container`

Stack snippet

```css
.flex-outer {
  display: flex;
}

.dashboard {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.col {
  margin-left: 25px;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;                       /*  added  */
  background: orange;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;                      /*  added  */
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  max-width: 200px;                     /*  added, to keep them max 200px  */
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-outer">
  <div class="dashboard">
    <ul class="flex-container">
      <li class="flex-item">1</li>
      <li class="flex-item">2</li>
      <li class="flex-item">3</li>
      <li class="flex-item">4</li>
      <li class="flex-item">5</li>
      <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was about to post the same.  :)

Comment: This is thorough! Thank you very much especially for the other options.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do is keep the right element (orange) in a fixed width and just shrink the left flex-item (red) based on the available space.

You can use the css calc function to achieve this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Based on the classnames you used, you can do something like this:

```
.col {
  width: 200px;
}

.flex-container {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `calc` until now. Is this supported in all browsers including the mobile ones?

Comment: @JohnnyQ Yes, and here you can see from which versions/browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=calc